# Sidekiq without Rails doesn't load worker classes

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq 3.1.2 **without Rails** like this:

```
$ sidekiq -vr sidekiq.rb
```

sidekiq.rb looks like this:

```
($LOAD_PATH << '.' << 'lib' << 'lib/workers').uniq!
require 'lookup_worker'
```

lib/workers/lookup_worker.rb looks like this:

```
require 'sidekiq'

class LookupWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(*args)
    puts "LookupWorker#perform fired with arguments #{args.map(&:inspect).join(', ')}"
  end
end
```

But when I'm in irb and try

```
> LookupWorker.perform_async('asdf')
```

it gives me this:

```
WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"LookupWorker", "args"=>["asdf"], "jid"=>"8c278868c5f05ec9beb1dbae", "enqueued_at"=>1402457226.9612548}
WARN: uninitialized constant LookupWorker
WARN: [backtrace, none of it from my code]
ERROR: Sidekiq::Processor crashed!
NameError: uninitialized constant LookupWorker
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So...

In `LookupWorker`, `require` was getting confused between `sidekiq` the gem and `sidekiq` the script on line 1.

My `sidekiq.rb` needed to be renamed as `sidekiq_script.rb` (or anything else really). Only gotcha is, I have to include the directory when running sidekiq:

```
$ sidekiq -r ./sidekiq_script.rb
```

not

```
$ sidekiq -r sidekiq_script.rb
```

Well I feel slightly stupid for that.

Comment: From some recent experience, I think that gotcha applies to `ruby` command-line `-r`equire options as well.